# Is it possible to get the user identity in a Citrix Client from .net application?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, citrix

I've got a .Net application running inside a Citrix environment and I need a way to identify the user logged on to the citrix client using forms authentication. Is this possible? I've seen some post regarding a Citrix SDK but not sure if solves my issue...

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface my statements by saying I know next to nothing about ASP.NET and Forms Authentication (which from brief Googling appears to be a way to implement custom auth in ASP.NET).

Any app running a Citrix session will have access to the identity of the user. It will be running as the users' identity already and so you can query the current security principal to see who the current user is. You don't need to use any special Citrix SDKs. It's a common assumption by devs that they need to do special stuff as soon as their app is running under Citrix. However in most cases you can develop your app as-if it were running on the users' local desktop, and just deploy it on a Citrix server instead.

So for a regular .NET desktop app you can use properties like: Environment.UserDomainName and Environment.UserName to get details about the current user. Other stuff of interest is System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity, you can use the GetCurrent() static method to get the current users' identity.

Now as I said initially this maybe different for your case as it sounds like forms authentication is some kind of custom auth mechanism, so what I've said may not apply. But hopefully I've given you some useful pointers.

Comment: What if there are 20 people, say, sharing 10 virtual desktops (day shift, night shift)? Is the identity linked to the virtual desktop or the person using it?

Comment: You tell me, how are users logging into the desktop? Have they all been given their own Windows login to use? If so you can use the techniques I suggest in the post, there is nothing really Citrix specific to worry about. You can just query the current logged in Windows identity.

Comment: We've just gotten a proposal and don't have Citrix installed yet. Users are all assigned individual logons and they log into the Windows domain using the normal Windows10 desktop authentication dialog.  How they will be logging into Citrix is not clear to me at this point, but I imagine they will open a browser and go to a URL, where there will be another logon dialog, since one of the requirements is that users must be able to work from out of the office.  It wasn't clear from the proposal whether they would be on a separate domain or if the Citrix domain was an extension of on-prem domain.

Comment: Generally you would use the same domain and the Citrix login will just be the Windows login. So there's really nothing Citrix to worry about in terms of writing your app. Just treat it like writing a local Windows app.